# Cant do Multiple on_message events in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want make a Discord bot that auto supports user...
I tried to do auto response!

I tried this both things!

Both gave me a Error and dindnt work
please help me.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if string.lower('Need') in message.content:
        if string.lower('Help') in message.content:
            await ctx.send("Test")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if string.lower('Hey') in message.content:
        if string.lower('i') in message.content:
            await ctx.send("Hola")


----------------------------And i Tryed this------------------------------------

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if string.lower('Hey') in message.content:
        if string.lower('i') in message.content:
            print('Keyword found in message')
        else:
    if string.lower('Test') in message.content:
        if string.lower('hi') in message.content:
            print('Keyword found in message')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Firstly, next time you post a question, please post the details of the error that you're encountering.

Secondly, the second implementation is more correct than the first. It just has a syntax error.

This should be correct:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if string.lower('Hey') in message.content:
        if string.lower('i') in message.content:
            print('Keyword found in message')
    
    if string.lower('Test') in message.content:
        if string.lower('hi') in message.content:
            print('Keyword found in message')
```

Comment: If you're still getting an error, please post that error so I can see it.

Comment: Thank you :D it really helped me :D